# Spark UI Showing Wrong Memory Allocation

Tags: apache-spark

We are currently running into an issue where Spark is showing that each of our nodes only have 4GB of memory. However, we have allocated 10GB of memory by setting `spark-worker.jvmOptions = -Xmx10g`. We can not figure out what is causing this unusual limitation/incorrect memory allocation.

When we go to run spark jobs it will run as if there is only 4GB of memory per worker.

Any help would be great! Thanks!

[Screenshot of SOLR UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aroMH.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should set worker memory using : `--executor-memory` in your spark-submit

Comment: I don't think ```---executor-memory``` would be the solution. That should be set to best optimize a spark job. Such as having 64GB of memory then the ```---executor-memory``` should be set to something like 19GB... more fun details in the link below.

https://blog.cloudera.com/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/

This issue is more that the actual Spark servers are not recognizing the memory being allocated to it with the jvm properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the following parameters inside the conf/spark-defaults.conf file:

```
spark.executor.memory           10g
```

Comment: The ```spark.executor.memory``` config actually does the same thing as the spark-submit parameter of ```---executor-memory```. So it will not affect the amount of memory being allocated to the JVM but just to the executors in the job.